# minimising total cost

Tags: calculus, optimization

A publishing company sells 75000 books during a year

It costs a publishing company 0.6 dollars to store a book for a year. Each time they print additional copies, setting up the printers cost $2500. Assuming constant demand, how many books should the company produce during each prints run in order to minimise total cost.

My attempt. Let $x$ be this number. Let $y$ be the no. of print runs. $xy$=7500. I can't figure out what the objective function is. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be the number of printruns per year, $n$ the number of books per print run. Obviously $p\cdot n = 75000$.

One important thought is that we only start a new print run when we have sold all books in the storage.

Per print run we now have a cost of $\frac{n\cdot 0.6}{2\cdot p}$ because right after the print run we have $n$ books that last $1/p$ years (untill the next print run). If you plot #books in storage vs time you see a sawtooth pattern: The spikes begin at each print run and linearly decrease to 0 until the next sprint run (*constant demand*). The area of each triangle is how many book$\cdot$years we have to pay the storage for. This area is $$\frac{n \cdot\frac{1}{p}}{2}$$. We have to multiply this number by $0.6$ and then we get the storage cost per printrun: $$\frac{n\cdot 0.6}{2\cdot p}$$ Since we do $p$ print runs the total storage costs are $$p \frac{n\cdot 0.6}{2\cdot p} = n\cdot 0.3$$. The total print run cost is $2500\cdot p$ So the total cost $c_{total}$ is

$$c_{total} = n\cdot 0.3+p\cdot 2500$$ We can now use that $pn=7500$ or $p = 7500/n$ and plug that in:

$$c_{total} = n\cdot 0.3+ 2500\cdot 75000/n$$

Since we want to minimize the total cost you now have to find the minimum of $c_{total}$.